# Two children swap places, except one was a dragon

Tags: story-identification, comics

I need help finding this one graphic novel book I believe that had a story from 2 kids perspectives I think they swap places, one was a dragon (I think) the other was human. I do remember a humanoid candle wax person though. I do remember that he cinder accidently set his sisters hair on fire.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  There aren't a lot of details here, so you should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if there's anything else you remember you can [edit] into your question.  When did you read this?  What was the art style?  Was it in English?